# recover one notepad++ from multiple notepad++ windowses closed in wrong sequence

Tags: windows-7, notepad++

I need your help. I had a notepad++ window with lots of (very) useful tabs. I've opened another notepad++ just to see some files, and by mystake I've closed the first (mentioned) window (i.e. the one with useful stuff). Although I've closed the second window, when I try to restart the notepad++, I only get the tabs from the second window...

How can I get the tabs from my first window back? (I would like to know them, and if possible to have them reopened in the same way)

I had also some tabs which didn't have theri content save to a file? Is it possible to recover them too?

Please help :) Thank you

PS I'm using notepad++ 6.6.6 - what an irony?

Answer (score 1):

Any backups of files unsaved in Notepad++ will be found at:

```
%AppData%\Notepad++\backup
```

Your open tabs are tracked in one file. Therefore, the last instance to be open will be the last one to write to that file. You could attempt to recover previous versions of your settings if you have that enabled at an OS level.

You would recover the last know good version of this folder:

```
%AppData%\Notepad++\
```

Else, your last resort is to just open those files again. They still exist.